# What is meaning of 002 value which is returned when umask command is executed in shell

Tags: shell, unix

I type the umask command in linux shell and it returns **002** as output.
I know what for umask command used. But what **002** represents.
please help me

Comment: 0x2 is `write`. Hence, files will not be writable by `others` by default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It shows the default permission levels by which a file will be created.
Subtracting umask from base permission would give you actual file permissions.
All the files will be created with `664` `(666-002)` permissions and dir with `775` `(777-002)` permissions.

Comment: imean which bit represents what?

Comment: The order is rwx (read-write-execute), and the bitmask is defined as r=4, w=2, x=1, so 002 equals w only.

Answer (score 0):

It means that files created will not be world-writable by default.